# A continuous path between shapes

Tags: geometry, continuity

Let $A$ and $B$ be two geometric shapes in the plane (two measureable subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$) such that $A\subseteq B$.

Define a $path$ from $A$ to $B$ as a function $f$ from $[0,1]$ to subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that:

- $f(0)=A$.
- $f(1)=B$.
- $f$ is monotonically increasing, i.e. for every $t'>t$, $f('t)\supseteq f(t)$.
- $Area(f(t))$ is a continuous function of $t$.

Intuitively, a path describes how the shape $A$ grows continuously until it becomes $B$. It makes sense that such a function exists. But how can I prove it?

Alternatively, if a path does not always exist, what are the conditions on $A$ and $B$ that guarantee that it does?

Comment: If the shapes were convex I could imagine shrinking A, translating till it was completely inside B then from a single point inside A, mapping each point of the boundery of A radially onto the boundery of B as a vague idea. Would that be possible if B were not convex (would it make any such mapping multi-valued?)

Comment: @Paul  $f$ is required to be monotonic increasing, so shrinking and translating aren't things we can do, fortunately we don't need to as we start with $A \subset B$

Comment: Sorry yes, you have that. A radial line from an interior point of A will identify a point on the boundery of A with a point on the boundery of B though. I could imagine making that interior point the centre of some disk containing B. Moving out radially from the centre to the disk boundery and taking $f(t) = f(t_0)$ after you hit the boundery of B at $t_0$ might give you a mapping with a bit of playing around. I would be worried that B is not convex though, then the map would be multi-valued?

Comment: In the discrete world of pixels, this can be trivially solved using Flood Fill. Maybe something similar could be used in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: Presumably the shapes are bounded in some way?

Comment: @copper.hat my main interest is in bounded shapes, but I don't if this matters for the current question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume $B$ is bounded.

If $A$ is nonempty, pick a point in $A$, call it $0$. Define $C_r$ ($r \geq 0$) to be the closed disc of radius $r$ around $0$. Since $B$ is bounded there exists $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $C_c \supset B$.

If $A$ is empty but $B$ is not then pick $0 \in B$, and define $C_r$ ($r \geq 0$) to be the open disc of radius $r$ around $0$; again since $B$ is bounded there exists $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $C_c \supset B$.

(If $A$ and $B$ are both empty the result is trivial).

Either way, define $f(t) = (A \cup C_{ct}) \cap B$ for $0 \leq t \leq 1$.

Clearly $f(0) = A$, $f(1) = B$, and $f$ is monotonically increasing.

Finally, that $Area(f(t))$ is continuous can be seen from the fact that $Area(C_{ct})$ is continuous and $Area(f(t+h)) - Area(f(t)) \leq Area(C_{c(t+h)}) - Area(C_{ct})$.

I think that if $B$ is not bounded then defining $f(t) =  (A \cup C_{\frac{t}{1-t}}) \cap B$ for $0 \leq t < 1$ and $f(1) = B$ works, but I don't know enough about measure theory to completely convince myself that $Area(f(t))$ is continuous at $1$ then.

Comment: This is a beautiful solution, thanks! I would like to cite your answer in a paper. What name can I use?

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi Christopher Fish. PS I've made a slight edit to cover the case when $A$ (or $B$) is empty, in case these matter to you.

Comment: I think that you can always pick a point in $B$, even if $A$ is non-empty.

Comment: Ah yes, so you can.